# Bing Reverse Image search from URL

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services, bing

I'm trying do to a bing reverse image search from an image url, but I can't get it to return anything other than Bad Request. Here's my code

```
var client = new VisualSearchClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("cred"));
var req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(imageUrl);
using Stream stream = req.GetResponse().GetResponseStream();
var visualSearchResults = client.Images.VisualSearchMethodAsync(image: stream, knowledgeRequest: (string)null).Result;
```

I also tried using WebClient

```
var client = new VisualSearchClient(new ApiKeyServiceClientCredentials("cred"));
WebClient wc = new WebClient();
using Stream s = wc.OpenRead(imageUrl);
var visualSearchResults = client.Images.VisualSearchMethodAsync(image: s, knowledgeRequest: (string)null).Result;
```

Anyone know how I can make this work?

Comment: Track the request/response through a tool like Fiddler and you should be able to see more details about the `Bad Request` error that you're getting.

Comment: The documentation says  "The knowledgeRequest parameter is not required if an image binary is passed in the request body", but details on the Bad Request says knowledgeRequest parameter has invalid value. If I include a VisualSearchRequest object instead of null as the knowledgeRequest parameter, I still get the same error.

Comment: As said by @GauravMantri, check the response content, it may have more details about the error. I have implemented calls to VisualSearch similar to yours, but using a Stream from a File, and it worked well

Answer (score 0):

I eventually got it working by downloading the image into a MemoryStream

```
var ms = new MemoryStream(new WebClient().DownloadData(imageUrl));
var visualSearchResults = client.Images.VisualSearchMethodAsync(image: ms, knowledgeRequest: (string)null).Result;
```